# How to execute vb code from from a vb app

Tags: vb.net

There are very few uses for this but is there a way to run some vb.net in a vb.net app. Now before you all downvote let me explain with an example. Lets say I have a vb app called app1, one of the things I want app1 to do is run another app (lets call it app2). However app2 hasn't been written, I only have the code (in a string within app1) that would be used in app2.

I believe this is the equivalent in matlab:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/eval.html

Comment: Broad question. Perhaps do some research into the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) first, and then you can post a more specific question as you start writing code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm looking specifically for a function that can be called thus: function(codeToRun). With the possible bonus of having a single value returned to the main program (not necessary though since the codeToRun could be appended with something to modify a text file that the main program checks).

Comment: There is no single function built in to do that - the CodeDOM is designed to allow you to write that functionality. If your question here is for someone to provide you with a full implementation of that in a single function (or refer you to something that does), it's inappropriate here and should be closed. It's far too broad in scope.

Comment: I'm not asking for code. I'm a firm believe in "the best way to learn is to do it yourself", but I wasn't aware if there was a single function as there is in matlab. That essentially was my question. So Thanks for the answer! I'll now proceed to spend the next few days leaning codeDOM. Wish me luck.

Comment: One possibility is the MS [ScriptControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227633(v=vs.60).aspx) which allows you to add objects, methods, etc. and eval/execute things in either VBScript or JavaScript.